# Disable an option for the select form field

Tags: 7, forms

How do I disable an option in the select form field?

```
$form['feed'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select', 
  '#title' => t('Display of XML feed items'), 
  '#options' => array(
    'title' => t('Titles only'), 
    'teaser' => t('Titles plus teaser'), 
    'fulltext' => t('Full text'),
  ),
  '#description' => t('Global setting for the length of XML feed items that are output by default.'),
);
```

How can I disable, for example, the "Title only" option?

Comment: This would be great to know how to do, I still want the option to appear in the list, but not be selectable...

Answer (score 6):

Disabling an option may be tricky to achieve ([Using form_alter to disable ONE option of a select field](http://drupal.org/node/803242)) so I'll recommend you to look at [optgroups](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp) as an alternative. The Drupal [form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html#options) documentation doesn't explain it but the API allows nested array for the options, have a look at [form_select_options()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_select_options) and the `<optgroup>` part.
You can write this code:

```
$form['feed'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select', 
    '#title' => t('Display of XML feed items'), 
    '#options' => array(
        'Titles only' => array(, 
          'teaser' => t('Titles plus teaser'), 
          'fulltext' => t('Full text'),
        ),
        'Titles only 2' => array(, 
          'teaser2' => t('Titles plus teaser 2'), 
          'fulltext2' => t('Full text 2'),
        ),
    ),
    '#description' => t('Global setting for the length of XML feed items that are output by default.'),
);
```

Have a look at [Drupal 6 forms and optgroup arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536484/drupal-6-forms-and-optgroup-arrays/1538973#1538973).

**Edit**: to clarify this is an alternative and not a direct answer.

Comment: The question is about disabling one of the options, not grouping them.

Comment: I understood that but I thought optgroup provided a good alternative.

Comment: brilliant! That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!!!

Answer (score 6):

The only way to disable one of the options for a "select" form field is to override the [theme_select()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_select/7) function implementing [hook_theme_registry_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7).

`theme_select()` executes the following code:

```
function theme_select($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'size'));
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-select'));

  return '<select' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . form_select_options($element) . '</select>';
}
```

The function that you implement should invoke your own function instead of [form_select_options()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_select_options/7).

As `theme_select()` is called for each select field used in any Drupal form, I would rather consider implementing [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to remove the option from the form field you want.

Answer (score 4):

I got mine working with the following line

```
unset($form['field_name']['und']['#options'][1]);
```

where 1 is the index of the item which you don't want to be displayed.

Comment: This removes the option. The question is about disabling the option (leaving it displayed grayed out).

Comment: True @Koen - for me personally, this was a quick and easy alternative solution that I implemented instead of going down the "disable" route. It allowed me to stop a user selecting a specific option for an active form, while leaving the option within the setup for archived/past submissions.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know and haven't been able to find any way to *disable* an individual option. It does look like they are trying to get something like this into Drupal. Maybe some alternatives, could what you want be done with css?:

```
$form['feed']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('options-styles-class'));
```

Or, if you don't want the values to be shown at all you can unset them

```
unset($form['feed']['#options']['title']);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Convert the one single item you want to disable into an empty `<optgroup>`.**

**Pros:**

- This can be done in a `hook_form_alter` or directly when building your custom form, there is no need to implement a `theme_select` function in your theme.

**Cons:**

- There's no way to represent the `value='title'` attribute associated with the original `<option>` in the resulting DOM.
- YMMV if you're trying to disable an option that already pertains to an optgroup. Nested optgroups might indeed work, but this is untested and unconfirmed.

**Implementation:**

Optgroups in Drupal are denoted inside the `#options` array as any `key => value` pairs where the value is itself an array.

So from the example in the OP we would **move the value of `t('Titles only')` to become the `key` and then make the value be an empty array.**

```
$form['feed'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select', 
  '#title' => t('Display of XML feed items'), 
  '#options' => array(
    t('Titles only') => array(), // This one becomes disabled as an empty optgroup
    'teaser' => t('Titles plus teaser'), 
    'fulltext' => t('Full text'),
  ),
  '#description' => t('Global setting for the length of XML feed items that are output by default.'),
);
```

The resulting HTML will look something like this:

```
<form>
  <div>
    <label>Display of XML feed items</label>
    <select>
      <optgroup>Titles only</optgroup>
      <option value="teaser">Titles plus teaser</option>
      <option value="fulltext">Full text</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For disabling the whole field, use

```
$form['field_name']['#disabled']= TRUE;
```

For disabling an option in the select field, use

```
unset($form['field_name']['und']['#options'][1]);
```

where:

*['field_name']* is the name of the your field

*[1]* is the index of the option in the list

Answer (score 0):

For drupal 8 or 9 you could take a look to the anwser on this page https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/207505/89554.

You have to install the module https://www.drupal.org/project/form_options_attributes

### Usage

To add attributes to a form element's options, add an **#options_attributes** key to the form element definition. The **#options_attributes** value should be an array with keys that match the keys in the **#options** value array. The values in the **#options_attributes** array should be formatted like the main **#attributes** array

### Exemple based on the question

Set the form field like this:

```
$form['states'] = [
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('Display of XML feed items'),
  '#options' => [
    'title' => t('Titles only'),
    'teaser' => t('Titles plus teaser'),
    'fulltext' => t('Full text'),
  ],
  '#options_attributes' => [
    'title' => ['disabled' => 'disabled'],
  ],
  '#description' => t('Global setting for the length of XML feed items that are output by default.'),
];
```

In our exemple pay attention on **#options_attributes** array where I set the attribute **disabled**