# How to create optgroups from taxonomy terms?

Tags: 7, forms

I have taxonomy terms with parent/child hierarchies (1 level deep). On a node edit page the terms are shown in a select box where I can select multiple terms.

What I'm trying to do is convert the parent terms into [optgroups](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp) so they cannot get selected and the children are nicely grouped. [This post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10027/disable-an-option-for-the-select-form-field) shows how to structure the form array.

Basically, the array needs to get arranged like this:

```
$form['field_disc_topic']['und']['#options'] = array (

   'parent1' => array(
    3 => 'child1',
    4 => 'child2',
    5 => 'child3',
    ),
    26 => 'parent2' => array(
    8 => 'child1',
    9 => 'child2',
    ),
);
```

This is the code I started with. A parent term has depth=0, children have depth=1. I can't figure out to how build the array:

```
$tax = taxonomy_get_tree(2);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($tax); ++$i) {
    debug( $tax[$i]->tid);
    debug($tax[$i]->name);
    debug($tax[$i]->depth);
}
```

Can anyone solve this? Or is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:
http://drupal.org/node/76500#comment-2193734

I posted the code used in the comment.  All props go to [Nate Anderson](http://drupal.org/user/471638) from [drupal.org](http://drupal.org)

```
<?php
if (isset($form['taxonomy'][$vid])) {
  $tree = taxonomy_get_tree($vid);
  $parent = "";
  $options = array();
  foreach ($tree as $term) {
    if ($term->depth == 0) {
      $parent = $term->name;
    }
    else {
      if ($term->depth > 1) {
        $options[$parent][$term->tid] = _modulename_spaces($term->depth, '-') . ' ' . $term->name;
      }
      else {
        $options[$parent][$term->tid] = $term->name;    
      }
    }
  }
  $form['taxonomy'][$vid]['#options'] = $options;
}

function _modulename_spaces($number, $char = ' ') {
  $output = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++) {
    $output .= $char;
  }

  return $output;
}
?>
```

Comment: brilliant, that's exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is module for that called as [optgroup select](https://www.drupal.org/project/optgroup_select). You can try that module.

PS: I am the module maintainer.