# Add attributes to options elements in a select box

Tags: 7, entities

I am working with a Drupal 7 site; I have a vocabulary setup with an additional text field. On one of my content-type nodes, this is rendered as a drop-down select box with all the terms under that vocabulary. However, I would also like for the additional vocabulary field to be included as a `data-country` attribute. It is rendered rendered as follows.

```
<select id="..." name="..." class="...">
    <option value="145">UK8</option>
</select>
```

I'd like it to be rendered as follows.

```
<select id="..." name="..." class="...">
    <option value="145" data-country="United Kingdom">UK8</option>
</select>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

There is [Form Options Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/form_options_attributes) module wich adds support for the attributes.

Answer (score 3):

Unfotunately there is no way to do it using Form API. You need to involve some theming. Please check the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9264589/2620782

Comment: Hey Inamil, thanks for the reply and the SO link. I'll check it out and post back here.